# Quiver invariants as polynomials/algebraic curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, mp.mathematical-physics, quivers

I'm interested in algebraic curves one can associate to gauge or string theories. Examples involve Seiberg-Witten curves or family of A-polynomials which define holomorphic Lagrangian submanifolds for $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ Chern-Simons theory or alternatively mirror Calabi-Yau manifolds to resolved conifold.

I'm wondering if something like this has been done for quiver gauge theories or quivers in general, for simplicity with symmetric quivers (or even general)? Are there any algebraic curves one can associate to quivers or quiver gauge theories that have some interpretations? Are there any quiver invariants that are algebraic curves? It would be really good if those curves were Riemann surfaces (or polynomials in two variables). I've heard of Nakajima quiver varieties but I don't know if they are algebraic curves.

Answer (score 1):

For quiver gauge theories the analog of Seiberg-Witten curves has been described by Nekrasov and Pestun https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.2240